# how can i save or write json file when i development chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, frontend

There was an issue during the development of Chrome extension.

I want to manage the config as a json file, so I made a **config.json** file and successfully reading it.

here's a read a json file code

```
    fetch("config.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      ..something codes
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

but the **config.json** file contains parameters that can be modified by the user, so it needs to be modified.

how can i modify it, Is this issue impossible to implement without the Chrome storage API?
i don't want to use chrome or web storages.

here is my manifest file

```
{
  ...
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "config.json"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
 ...
}
```

Comment: An extension can't modify its files, the browser disables an extension if any of its files change.